# Windows 10 update stuck and setting screen is slow to load

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

Whenever I open the windows update screen, I'm being greeted by the following message, as shown in the pictures.

[image]

Alternatively:

[image]

This has been the case with my laptop for days. Please help me resolve this.

Comment: Try [this](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-update/downloading-windows-update-stuck-at-0/cdb1a9be-7e4c-4de2-8e4b-47379d6a3d9a) answer.

Comment: Thanks. That worked. Sorry I didn't reply earlier.

Comment: Great. Good to hear.